# Display php script in VScode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

plug-ins or extension for PHP in VS code

Hello, I have always run into this error when I tried to execute php script on VS code, today I wanted to print "Hello world!", But it kept displaying an error message in the terminal. Please help me in overcoming this error.

Comment: What error message is it displaying?

Comment: Did you put `<?php` at the beginning of the script? If not, it won't be executed as code, it will just be literal text.